# How to send multiple response as output to Gradio Chatbot

Tags: chatbot, large-language-model, gradio, gradio-chatinterface

As per the Gradio docs, the Chatbot function expects the output in the format `List[List[str | None | Tuple]]`. However, I am unable to find a way I can send back a response to Chatbot so that it looks like multiple responses. Maybe the screenshot below can convey what I am looking for:

[image]

As you can see from the above screenshot, I added multiple queries as a user but the desired output is a bot sending back multiple responses.